# C++ design: Given a list of scores of students, get the frequence of scores in order

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl, dictionary

I have a C++ interview question:

Given a list of scores of students, get the frequence of scores in order.
[use c++ container map]

My idea: put the list of scores into a map with score as key and frequency as value. Before add a key, search it. If a key is new, add it and set its freq as 1. If not, update its freq by ++1.  O(nlgn)

Then, reverse key and value in a new map, in which set freq as key and its score as value.  O(nlgn) because map do sorting itself.

memory: O(n)

It is not very efficient because I have to use 2 maps and do sorting 2 times.

Any comments or ideas are welcome.

Thanks

---

```
  My code


    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    #include <algorithm>

    #include <time.h>

  using namespace std;
  const int M =10;
  int A[M] ;
  bool myFunc(pair<int, int> p1 , pair<double, int> p2)
  {
    //return p1.second > p2.second;
  }

   int scoreMap(int *A, const int& N)
   {
    if (A == NULL)
            return 1;
    map<int, int> map1;
    map<int, int>::iterator itr;
    int j = 0 ;
    while(j < N)
    {
            int myKey = (A[j]) ;
            itr = map1.find(myKey);
            if (itr == map1.end())
            {
                    map1.insert(pair<int, int>(myKey, 1));
            }
            else
            {
                    ++(itr->second);
            }
            ++j;
    }
    // print map1
    cout << "socre \t freq " << endl;
    for(itr = map1.begin(); itr != map1.end(); ++itr )
    {
            cout << itr->first << "\t" << itr->second << endl;
    }
    // use multimap
    multimap<int, int> map2;
    multimap<int, int>::iterator itr2;
    for (itr = map1.begin() ; itr != map1.end() ; ++itr )
    {
            map2.insert(pair<int, int>((*itr).second, (*itr).first)) ;
    }

    // print map2
    cout << "after sort " << endl;
    cout << "freq \t socre " << endl;
    for(itr2 = map2.begin(); itr2 != map2.end(); ++itr2 )
    {
            cout << (double)(itr2->first)/N << "\t" << itr2->second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
   }

   int main()
   {
    int N = 10;  int range=10;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < M ; ++i)
    {
            srand(time(NULL)+rand());
            //A[i] = rand()%range + (double)rand()/INT_MAX;
            A[i] = rand()%range ; // + (double)rand()/INT_MAX;
    //      sleep(1);
    }
    scoreMap(A, M);
    return 0;
   }
```

// EOF

time O(nlgn), space O(n), are there more efficient solutions ? 
thanks

Comment: Are there limits on what the scores can be?  Will they be integral types?  Are they in a bound range?  What is the order to return the frequency of scores?

Comment: Do you have to use map? Can you use unordered_map?  If you know you need to resort, why pay log(n) for inserts.

Comment: unordered_map with <score, frequency> -> vector -> resort on frequency.

Comment: the score can be int or float. It is in the range [1, 100].

Comment: map must be used. but, you can propose a better solution after showing how to do it with map.

Answer (score 3):

Assume the score is a narrow integer range (1-100)

The score accumulation is stored in an array[score-range] of pairs, with your ++[score] idea.

The extraction of the frequencies is made by moving down the score list in an iterative fashion.  O(N+M) N score range + M number of results/scores. Sort the result.

Sample pseudo:

```
const size_t MAX_SCORE = 100; //  Min is assumed 0.
void scoreFrequencies(int [] scores, size_t N){
    pair<int,int> score_counts[MAX_SCORES];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++){
        score_counts[i].first++;
        score_counts[i].second = i;
    }
    sort( score_counts, score_counts+MAX_SCORES );
    for(size_t score_decreasing = MAX_SCORES-1; 
             score_counts[score_decreasing].first!=0 && score_decreasing >=0; 
             score_decreasing--)
         cout<< (score_counts.second) <<": " << 
                 ( score_counts.first*1.0/N ) << endl;
}
```

As can be seen, by this method, the ordering of score_counts before sort( ... ) is unnecessary, so a `map` would not help.

Comment: @Mooing No not at all, the index is the score, the value is the number of occurrences. Sum the scores in the iteration or get the number of students in the list; and Bob's you uncle.

Comment: `Sort the result.` Alright, you've got a sorted list of `int`s.  How many got 100%?

Comment: @Mooing, thanks, please look at the pseudo, I think it is fair.

Comment: you don't define `sort_on_first`, but you don't need the predicate anyway, `pair` overloads `operator<`.  Also during output you underrun the buffer if every score was gotten at least once.  And the output is "score: <fraction that got score>"?  I guess that works.

Comment: the output is score:frequency

Comment: @Mooing, pair overloads op <() ? That was big news to me. Well the formatting of the output is considered an exercise to the reader =)

Comment: Heh, removed the undefined `sort_on_first`, but not the buffer underrun?  Priorities!  Also, `std::pair::operator<()` makes a LOT of things easier.  Like, `std::map`.

Comment: I wrote sample pseudo. I do not expect any compiler to actually compile this. This code is to be read by humans, passing the turing test.

Comment: it's fixed now.  Maybe I overlooked it somehow.

Comment: Also @Mooing, are you actually trying to compile this :-)

Comment: Nope, just eyeballing.  But supplying code with a buffer underrun (especially when it's a naked array!) is just cruel.

Comment: @Mooing I tried to move this into chat, but there seems to be a pebkac bug.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4277/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-captain-giraffe)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use a map, simply define a histogram of all the scores using an array-type of `std::pair<int, int>`.  One member will be the scores, and the other the frequency.  Initially the scores will be the same value as the array-index they are at, but you should only do this initialization when you try to access each specific score index, otherwise you will end up initializing a bunch of scores that don't exist. Then sort the array based on frequency of the scores after you've filled in the histogram for the scores themselves.  Since the scores in the histogram basically act like very simple hash-lookup, the overall time should be very fast (... O(1) for each score-lookup and associated frequency increment, and O(n log n) for sorting).

Here's a little bit of code to help explain:

```
std::pair<int, int> scores[SCORE_RANGE] = {0}; //zero-out the entire array

//...iterate through your score data
for (int i=0; i < SCORE_DATA_SIZE; i++)
{
    int score_val = raw_score_data[i];

    if (scores[score_val].first == 0)
    {
        scores[score_val].first = score_val;
    }

    scores[score_val].second++;
}

//now sort your scores array based on the frequency which is stored in the second
//member of the std::pair structure
```

Comment: You can't store "just the scores" in the histogram, because if you're going to resort on another "key" (frequency) you need to keep the score in the histogram as well.  The concept is good though, if scores are in a small enough range.

Comment: Keep in mind I'm proposing that the scores are the array indexes themselves, not the values stored at each array index. If the scores are too far apart, then yes, you will end up with too many "empty" areas in the array, but because the sorting time is still O(n log n), and the insertion time is O(1), this will be faster than using a `std::map`.  Also if you wanted to quickly get rid of the empty areas, you could initialize them to a MAX_VALUE+1 so that they all, after the sort, index at the end of the array, and you simply take all the values in the array that do not equal MAX_VALUE+1.

Comment: Oops, Okay I see what you're saying ... sorting the array will lose track of the index it was originally at.  So yes, it will have to be something like an array of `std::pair<int, int>`.  The complexity of the operations will still stay the same though.

Answer (score 0):

> My idea: put the list of scores into a map with score as key and frequency as value.

So far, so good,

> Before add a key, search it. If a key is new, add it and set its freq as 1. If not, update its freq by ++1. O(nlgn)

Checking for the existing of a map entry is unneeded and wasteful. The entry will spring into existence (with a default value) the fist time it is referenced. Just do this:

```
++scoreMap[score];
```

This doesn't change your big-O, but it does make it go faster.

> Then, reverse key and value in a new map, in which set freq as key and its score as value. O(nlgn) because map do sorting itself.

You can't use a new map, because the score won't necessarily be unique. But you could use `set<pair>`.

In honor of Ubuntu 11.10 (and g++ 4.6!) installing correctly on my PC, here is how one could use lambdas to solve this:

```
  map<int, int> scoreMap;
  for_each(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>(),
    [&scoreMap] (int i) { ++scoreMap[i]; } );
  set<pair<int,int>> freqMap;
  for_each(scoreMap.begin(), scoreMap.end(),
    [&freqMap] (const pair<int,int>& p) {
      freqMap.insert(make_pair(p.second, p.first));
    } );
  for_each(freqMap.rbegin(), freqMap.rend(),
    [] (const pair<int,int>& p) {
      cout << p.second << "/" << p.first << "\n";
    } );
```

Comment: @dtustudy68 - you don't need to sort a set. It is stored in sorted order.